# Programmer using Request.UserHostAddress wants an integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipv4

I'm using `Request.UserHostAddress` in a C# ASP.NET MVC web application to get the IP address of the client.

`Request.UserHostAddress` returns a string which is simple enough to convert into its integer form. However, this appears to be 2 levels of inefficiency because deep in the bowels of the .Net stack it probably takes the integer representation of the IP address and converts it to a string before my code converts it back to an integer.

Can I get the integer representation of the client's IPv4 address directly from .NET?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that it might be probably easier to migrate this code to IPv6 some day if you kepp using the string representation of the address at all places in your code that don't actually need to deal with the actual IPv4 data. Parsing and creating such strings should be some orders of magnitude faster than anything that involves actual networking to take place. So this is probably not the performance botteneck if you have to do it i.e. only a few times per existing connection.

Comment: IP is inspected on each visit

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. Are you saying you need the integer representation yourself? Surely in any display or reporting purposes, you would want to see the normal IP address notation, not the 32-bit integer representation of it. And that would result you converting it back again into a decent readable format, which is the kind of conversion you want to avoid...

Comment: Yes - I need the integer representation to work with. This is not for reporting purposes.